# AWS Lambda subprocess module not found error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, operating-system, subprocess, command-line-interface

Good afternoon,

I have been setting up some code for extracting text with fitz library (PyMuPDF).
Module has been correctly installed via lambda layer and it is working as expected, but when i try to use the official fitz utils script i get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fitz'
```

example code:

```
def extract_text(pdf_stream):
    try:
        pdf_doc = fitz.open(stream=pdf_stream, filetype='pdf')
        
        # Save the PDF document to a file
        pdf_doc.save('/tmp/file.pdf') #/tmp is a file destination required to save file, everything else is read only in lambda
        
        logger.info("PDF file saved. Running fitzcli.py.")
        cmd_args = ["python", "fitzcli.py", "gettext", "-input", "file.pdf", "-output", "tmp/extracted_text.txt", "-mode", "layout"]
        subprocess.run(cmd_args, check=True)

        with open('extracted_text.txt', 'r') as open_file:
            read_file = open_file.read()
        # Assuming extract_top_rows function is defined elsewhere in your code
        headers_text = extract_top_rows(read_file)
        
        return headers_text

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        raise
```

link of the script
https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/text-extraction/fitzcli.py

i cannot alter code because of the licensing contraints

i have tried copying lambda execution enviroment and run subprocess with that env.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
cmd_args = ["python", "fitzcli.py", "gettext", "-input", "file.pdf", "-output", "tmp/extracted_text.txt", "-mode", "layout"]
subprocess.run(cmd_args, check=True, env=env)
```

was expecting to run subprocess

Comment: A few checks you can perform - check what you get on `pip list` and also double check that there is import `import fitz`.

Answer (score 0):

@simpleApp fitz is imported fine as this part of the code executes

> pdf_doc = fitz.open(stream=pdf_stream, filetype='pdf')

apparently, the [PYTHONPATH] was not set correctly only when using subprocess.
So the fix was to point it to module path and pass the copy of lambda execution enviroment to subprocess

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PYTHONPATH'] = '/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages'
cmd_args = ["python", "fitzcli.py", "gettext", "file.pdf", "-output", "/tmp/extracted_text.txt", "-mode", "layout"]
subprocess.run(cmd_args, check=True, env=env)
```